# Не запускается Laravel-сервер

Tags: php, laravel

`laravel` не запускает сервер через  `OpenServer`

Ввожу:

```
cd domains|
cd fnc-master|
php artisan serve
```

Выводится:

```
Warning: require(C:\OSPanel\domains\fnc-master/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\OSPanel\domains\fnc-master\artisan on line 18
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\OSPanel\domains\fnc-master/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.') in C:\OSPanel\domains\fnc-master\artisan on line 18
```

Comment: Файл `C:\OSPanel\domains\fnc-master/vendor/autoload.php` существует ?

Answer (score 1):

Команда **php artisan serve** - это просто ярлык для встроенного PHP Webserver, в то время как вы хотите использовать **OpenServer**.
Поэтому верный порядок установки и запуска Laravel в OpenServer следующий:

- установить composer если еще не установлен
- `composer create-project laravel/laravel fnc-master`
- проверить есть ли файл .env в директории fnc-master и если нет тогда скопировать файл .env.example в .env
- создать БД в openServer и прописать её реквизиты в .env файле
- проверить заполнен ли параметр APP_KEY в файле .env и если нет тогда выполнить команду

```
php artisan key:generate
```

- Profit!